# Reccuring billing in authorize.net ios sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, credit-card, recurring-billing

I am developing an ios application that accepts creditcard payments using Authorize.net sdk.
Its working fine after lot of work.

But now I need to implement thr recurring billing with the same.
But I can't see any methods or API calls in the sdk. But everybody telling that Authorize.e supports recurring billing. Is there any method for implementing recurring billing in Authorize.net ios a

Answer (score 0):

The iOS SDK for Authorize.Net doesn't support Automated Recurring Billing. You can check this out on the below link. ARB api is available for other languages alongwith it's source code also, but not for iOS.

http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/Recurring-billing-possible-in-ios/td-p/34688

Comment: I don't think it will work.....WHat u can do is u can set the AUtomatic Recuring Billing on from the merchant's account plus you have to notify the user that this is ARB and the preferred amount will be deducted at regular time interval being set from the merchant's account.Don't forget to notify the user about it. Have you tried implementing XML api?